# nodejs + typescript no reconoce ninguna de las rutas

Tags: nodejs, typescript

Estoy desarrollando mi backend Nodejs con Typescript, Mongo y Express, pero al momento de usar las rutas ninguna de ellas es encontrada:

```js
routes = (controllers: IController[]) => {  
  controllers.forEach((controller: IController) => {
    this.app.use('/api/', controller.router);
  });
};
```

Declaro las rutas y estas no trabajan al parecer. El router no está sirviendo, puse log en el método que declara las rutas y si entra, también puse logs en el for y este también entra.

```js
controllers.forEach((controller: IController) => {
  console.log('inside');
  this.app.use('/api/', controller.router);
});
```

También probé poniendo manualmente mi ruta y este sirvió.

```js
routes = (controllers: IController[]) => {  
  this.app.use('/api/',(req,res)=>{
    console.log('inside');
  });    
};
```

Mi interface IController :

```js
export interface IController{
  path:string;
  router:Router;
  initRoutes():void;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo resolvi esto especificando de nuevo que es un tipo Router de express y en este momento sirvio todas las rutas

```
routes = (controllers: IController[]) => {  
  
    controllers.forEach((controller: IController) => {    
      const routeTemp :Router = controller.router;
      this.app.use('/api/', controller.router);
    });
  };
```

Comment: Si consideras que esta es la solución que buscas para tu problema te sugiero que cierres la pregunta

Comment: @AnkiJedi cualquier aporte es bueno, quien sabe, tal vez la solución le sirva a otras personas

Comment: @Christian, perdon! soy nuevo en el sitio y puede que haya usado mal el termino, ¿cuando cierras una pregunta esta no queda guardada? Lo habia dicho porque en otra pregunta decian que si no la cerraban el bot de comunidad podia seleccionarla a futuro

Comment: @AnkiJedi, las preguntas cerradas quedan en el sitio, pero lo mas probable es que alguien las elimine, el autor no puede cerrar su pregunta, solo eliminarla, Ademas el bot comunidad elije las preguntas sin respuestas aceptadas

Comment: listo chicos pasa que me toca esperar 2 dias para aceptar la respuesta